# Простые шашки на python kivy

Tags: python, tkinter, kivy

Необходим код простых шашек на python kivy и возможно ли реализовать при помощи kivy? везде просматриваю варианты с tkinter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не знаю где вы "везде" просматривали, но я нашёл 2 репозитория на гитхабе, в которых, то что вам нужно.
[Первый](https://github.com/mateuszwwwrobel/CheckersGame)
[Второй](https://github.com/WesBAn/kivy_python_checkers)

Comment: спасибо, я новичок на гитхабе и теряюсь в потоках информацию, хоть и пытаюсь искать)